# Testlink Test cases location with Wamp server

Tags: server, wamp, testlink

I had a problem with my WAMP server not being online so after some hours changing values on Httpd.conf i was finally able to make it go online after all, with all of it's services too. But when i try to access localhost it only says "It's working!" and i can't access the testlink webpage. I had already done about 350 test cases manually into testlink so I REALLY want to get that back. I made a backup before the server went down of the entire WAMP directory but i have no idea where the test cases are located. They are not saved as they were named in TestLink. Anyone can show me the way?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If when you run `localhost` and it say `"It's working!"` then you have another version of Apache installed on this machine, and that is the one that is running and NOT the WAMPServer version of Apache.

As you are obviously learning, stick to one Apache per machine. So uninstall the other Apache completely. It would also be a good idea to look for another MYSQL as well. They travel in groups normally.